# How do I dump the contents of a dictionary into a UITextView or UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uilabel, uitextview

I am trying to display the contents of a dictionary into either a `UITextView` or `UILabel`. I can successfully do it using `println()` but when trying to add the values to a .text property it only adds the first line.

```
for (x, y) in dict
{
    println("\(x): \(y)")
    display.text = "("\(x): \(y)") // prints only first item
    display.text = "\(dict)" // prints [item1: 1, item2: 2....] I need it on separate lines and no []. 
}
```

Comment: Not sure why there is 3 times " in "("\(x): \(y)")

Comment: i was just displaying the 3 ways that i have tried and which ways worked and didnt

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Are you asking for "(x: y)" on multiple lines in a string?  Use the newline escape character:

```
var fullDict = ""

for (x, y) in dict {
    fullDict += "(\(x): \(y))\n"
}

display.text = fullDict
```

Comment: so the values in the dictionary are x: y. and i want to print out all values within the dictionary each value on a different line

x1: y1
x2: y2
x3: y3

Comment: Yes i did and it worked. Thank you! Appreciate the quick help.